# Can't find Localhost files

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, localhost, phpmyadmin

Hope you can help.  This is my first time trying Ubuntu/Linux.

I am logged in as root
I have downloaded and installed LAMP and PHPMYADMIN.
I get the test page under localhost say that It works and is installed Correctly.
I have also put my files in the `/var/www`. they are PHP files
When I put the address localhost/(page name.php) I get an error saying

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I Have put the files in the wrong folder?? If I look in the "`/etc/ap[ache2/sites-available/default`", It tells my my `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www`

Would love somehelp on this please

Many thanks
GF

Comment: How did you install LAMP and phpmyadmin?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to add the output of `ll -L /var/www`

Comment: did you name you `page name.php` `index.php` cause as the error says can't find `index.php`

Answer (score 2):

Check out error log (`tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`) in order to find out exact path that Apache tries to find.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using the apache logs I've found that the solution is to place your php code inside /html folder so -

```
sudo mv /var/www/FILENAME.php /var/www/html
```